# Does specific immunity affect the incubation period of viruses?

Tags: immunology, virology, coronavirus, epidemiology

My interest was inspired by the observed variation in incubation times for different strains of Covid-19, however I ask the question in the broader sense as it seems hard to find an answer in general.

Does the presence of immunity affect the duration of incubation period? I would have thought the body's ready ability to identify and defend against a virus may mean that it is identified sooner following infection. But I can't find evidence to confirm or refute this idea. Would really appreciate any thoughts!

Thanks

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure on the question here - once a virus enters a cell it will replicate at approx the same rate no matter whether there is an immune response. Immune response could prevent infection/limit infection, but won't affect replication kinetics.

Comment: I feel contradiction: if there is "incubation" there is bound to be "no immunity".

Comment: @bob1 It was a question of what is really happening during incubation. During incubation the virus is replicating undetected, but at some point it becomes detected and is no longer in the incubation phase. So I'm curious whether having a better immunity to a particular virus would result in a quicker detection in this phase, therefore shortening the incubation phase. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @PeterBernhard that's not true at all. The evidence is all around you - people who have been vaccinated are still getting sick with the omicron variant. Granted, not *as* sick as with other well-publicized strains, but sick nonetheless. The same thing happens with delta, to a lesser extent. So clearly, people with (good) immunity can still have virus incubation and eventually illness.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks to your comment I now feel better ... with the question that seems to have incubated on me, just as your comment seems to have. 
I will delete that expression of my feelings up above, as it hurts. Sure, me too, I have been misunderstood:  it's in your parenthesis, what I was up to, i.e. how can you use the word well - immunity - if incubation is evidence for its failure which is non existence. That is a debate on words and definition. Maybe more, though. (What is: symptomless infection) I feel understood. Still, I will delete my comment. I always did agree with all you say.

Comment: @MattDMo Amending my comment with the help of your comment I would say that the phrasing of the question "specific immunity" makes you think - first guess - of a kind of immunity that is effectiv (again, your parenthesis, to me are of importance). 
The phrasing does not immediately let youknow what the point is: does specific immunity as a very good immunity shorten or prolong incubation  in cases that you list, i.e. in cases of break through infection, vaccine failure. That word vaccine failure does not go well with "specific immunity" in a head line. I still insist, but will delete.

Comment: The wording of the question does not seem convey what it is about: If there is enhanced, "specific" immunity, the incubation period of a  break through infection (vaccine failure might be  some inappropriate term) should be prolonged 
- as with specific immunity which is good ammunition the fight should last longer before it is lost and incubation becomes "success". 
By intuition, the answer should run: yes, immunity affects the incubation period, the more  specific and thus the better the immunity the longer the fight, the longer the breakin' the immunity, the longer the  incubation time.

Comment: Does this question also refer to "symptomless infection"? I think it is important to be clear about definition of word: can there be spoken of "incubation" if there will never by any "symptoms"? Interestingly, your question is of practical relevance: thanks to vaccination people might either prolong their being infective to some indefinite point in the future - good to know -- and, counterintuitively, it is not at all trivially clear that (specific) immunity does not shorten the incubation - "period" :-) Seriously: it does not occur easily that good immunity just cannot shorten incubation.

Comment: You refer to "symptomless infection", too?  Can there be spoken of "incubation" if there will never by any "symptoms" (two terms mutually defined)? Of practical relevance: Thanks to vaccination people might either prolong their becoming infective to some indefinite point in the future - good to know. 
It is not at all trivially clear that (specific) immunity does not SHORTEN - just cannot -  the incubation - "period" :-) Seriously: it does not occur easily that good, specific immunity just cannot shorten incubation time. @Bob: no "influence" of immunity on "virus as is"?

Comment: @PeterBernhard, I think you need to have a good look at the role of immunity in infection. Good immunity means infection is limited in some way. This will not prolong their being infective indefinitely. Either the virus will enter the cell and replicate, or it will not enter and no infection results. Replication kinetics of the virus are key. Good immunity results in lower levels of infection because virus that exits the cell will be absorbed by the immune response faster and to greater levels than with poor immunity. Not longer infection!

Comment: @PeterBernhard In fact, it is the other way around: Prior immunity shortens the observed incubation period. See my (now edited) answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

There are two effects that can shorten the observed incubation period in presence of prior partial immunity

1. Symptoms are caused mainly by the reaction of the body, not by the virus itself. When there is some prior immunity, the immune response kicks in faster, leading to an earlier onset of symptoms. This effect is genuine.
2. When the infection proceeds somewhat slowly, it may be completely terminated by the immune response without any symptoms occurring. This effect cuts off the long tail of slow infections, leading to a shorter average incubation period.

EDIT: Not a publication but a Twitter thread by a renowned scientist (Micheal Mina) confirming [shortening of incubation period by immunity](https://twitter.com/michaelmina_lab/status/1561927371711807489).